# Force field lines in surface ice

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, ice

The question [Melting ice pattern](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56726/melting-ice-pattern) shows a single hole melted in ice. The picture below shows multiple holes of the type described in that question, and there are lines in the ice between the melted holes that look like force field lines. What causes the lines we can see in the image?

For a larger version of the image see https://bit.ly/RamFlikr-IceForceFields.
[image]

Comment: Start here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_mechanics